# how to append the whole form with value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

When i tried it append the only *values* but i want to append the whole block with *value* in it please help.

PHP Form:

```
<div class="addhere"></div>

<label for="element-1" class="control-label">Enter Item Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="iname" id="iname" class="form-control"/><br/>

<label for="element-2" class="control-label">Quantity</label>
<input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="form-control"/>

<br/>
<input type="button" id="additem" value="Add Item">
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#additem').click(function(){
        var iname=$('#iname').val(); 
        var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
        $('.addhere').append(iname,quantity);
    }); 
});
```

So how to append the new form with *value* in it.

Comment: where is your php code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add a new item inside addthere, correct? try this.

```
$('.addhere').append('<div> Element:' + iname + ' (' + quantity + ')</div>');
```

here is an example:
http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-append-and-appendto-example/

hope it helps.

Comment: thank but i want to duplicate the form as well. please help

Comment: your not using a tag form, Do you want to duplicate the hole form to a new id or put the new fields inside the same form? I don't know if Im clear, let me know. And what informations do you want to submit? thanks

Comment: I want to put value in the form and when i click the add button then it will not submit but the form and value are in there and a new form is appeared(same above form) and i can enter the new value(2nd item name) in new form below the previous one. Please help me by providing jquery (ajax) code. Please

Comment: Please, see if this example helps you. I found this example and adapted to get the last name and quantity of the last input.

http://jsfiddle.net/benera/v2y45n19/

This is the example I've found:
http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery